# Simplify multiple rest calls Java spring

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

My rest service need to use data f I'm other service.. To get the data I have to make 3 calls to the same servic who h different endpoints. I use rest template and sequentially call one after other sinc output of first call is input to other. What is the best practice to keep code clean in this? I don't like my code cluttered with these calls..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a composite service and hide internal calls (3 calls) behind it.

1. Expose your composite service say MyService
2. inside MyService make calls to ExternalService1, ExternalService2, ExternalService3
3. Return reponse from MyService

Comment: Is there a simpler way?